# How to create a reusable instant (non-duration) Java FlightRecorder JFR event?

Tags: java, profiling, jfr

I'm working on adding custom flight recorder events to track some of our KPI's and making them exposed through flight recording dumps.

One problem that beats me though is how to flag an event as either being an "instant" or "duration" based event.

https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/about.htm#JFRUH171

From my limited testing it seems like calling `commit` on an event which you later reuse (say in a ThreadLocal) makes the second & upcoming calls to `commit` include an end timestamp and a duration between the second commit and first.
This doesn't really fit my current use-case where I'm not interested in the timing between event creation and the commit call.

It seems to me that if you always instantiate new events and omit calling `begin` you **do** construct an event that has no duration - but for performance reasons I'd rather avoid the overhead introduced by generating new events each time and limit heap allocations.

Answer (score 1):

All events are durational in the sense they contain a field called duration.  If you call `commit()` without calling `begin()` or `end()`, the duration will be set 0. It will add one byte per event in the file and the overhead is negligible.  When it comes to caching and reusing event instances, it's not supported, but it can work in some scenarios.

The recommended way is to create an object per event. In most cases, the JIT is able to eliminate the allocation if the object doesn't escape. That is, leave the method you are using the event object in.

This video describe the process for disabled events, but some of the optimization applies to enabled events as well.
https://youtu.be/plYESjZ12hM?t=1126

([Escape analysis](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/EscapeAnalysis) is likely to improve over time and perhaps [primitive objects](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/401) can be used in the future. Caching in thread locals may turn out to be an anti-pattern, especially with [virtual threads](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main/#Main-VirtualThreads) coming soon)

Comment: Thanks Kire! That video from Mikael is the best explanation of escape analysis & dead code elimination I've seen, would love more examples of best practices when it comes to custom events.
2 follow up questions:

- Most custom event examples sets mutable fields instead passing in to event constructors. Is this due to JIT elimination best practices or are they interchangeable?
- JVM internal events seems to construct/commit events using `EventHandlers` rather than instance methods. Is this done for performance reasons and should we strive for something similar in performance critical code?

Comment: One reason to set fields instead of using the constructor is to guard expensive operations (that can't be dead eliminated) with "if (event.shouldCommit()) { event.x = foo(); ... }" In other cases, I don't know if constructor is faster, or not. When it comes to internal events, we noticed the JIT was unable to eliminate the allocation for some events (possibly due to exception handling). https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187234 so we have some temporary hacks in the JDK.

Comment: Ok, that's a good point about keeping constructors thin.
I worked around that by asking the cached `EventType` if it's enabled or not and delaying constructing the event.